# Are there any unordered, repeatable Collection classes in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I want a collection contains unordered, repeatable items.
In Java, Set is unrepeatable, List is ordered, which are not what I want.

It seems Pool is an appropriate collection, but it doesn't exist in Java.
The interface should be as following:

```
public interface Pool<T> {
    void set(T item);
    T get();
}
```

Does it exist somewhere?

---

**Complementing：**

I realize that I expressed my thought incorrectly. Infact, I want to have an interface like this:

```
public interface Pool<T> {
    void put(T item);
    T randomRemove();
}
```

That is to say, I want to get an item ramdomly everytime. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Try guava library.

Comment: That interface is really barebones. What are `set` and `get` supposed to be? Is `set` "put a `T` in" and `get` "remove and return a `T`"? If so, most of the ordered collections support that just fine with `add` and some variation of `remove` or `pop`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're looking for a collection that is explicitly unordered? Being ordered hardly seems like an impediment.

Comment: Guava's `HashMultiset` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement your `Pool<T>` functionality by wrapping a `List<T>`.

```
public class ListPool<T> implements Pool<T> {
    private List<T> list = ArrayList<>();

    public void put(T t) {
        list.append(t);
    }

    public T randomRemove() {
        return list.remove(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
    }
}
```

That won't be particularly efficient because `remove` is `O(N)` on the standard `List` implementations.  However, there is an alternative implementation using `ArrayList` that is a bit more complicated, but provides a `randomRemove` that is `O(1)`.  The idea is to treat the list as a dynamic array and manage the "size" yourself.

Something like this:

```
public class FasterPool<T> implements Pool<T> {
    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private int size = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();

    public void put(T t) {
        if (size == list.size()) {
            list.append(t);
        } else {
            list.set(size, t);
        size++;
    }

    public T randomRemove() {
        int pos = rand.nextInt(size);
        T result = list.get(pos);
        if (pos < size - 1) {
            list.set(pos, list.get(size - 1));
        }
        list.set(size - 1, null);  // avoid memory leak ...
        size--;
        return result;
    }
}
```

NB: neither version handles the case where the pool is empty when you try to remove an element.  Neither has been compiled or tested.  Please treat the code accordingly.

Finally, if you try to implement using a collection type that is not ordered, then you are unlikely to be able to remove a random element efficiently.  Hint: removing the first one returned by a collection's iterator will not be truly random for any practical collection data structure.  This would also apply to a (hypothetical) `Bag` implementation.

Comment: In the `FasterPool` snippet, couldn't we do without managing our own `size` if we swap the element at random position with the last element, and then remove the last element?

Comment: Great answer. But I suddenly thought of a question that, does it always have the uniform probability for every item when you exchange the position with some of them?

Comment: @JaeHeonLee - Yes.  That would work.

Comment: @jinge - yes it does.  At each stage you are using a PRNG with a uniform distribution to select one element from an "array".  The fact that an element is at a different positions in the array does not affect that.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be describing the Guava [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), and more specifically [`HashMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html).

No such collection exists in Java SE, although you could build your own fairly easily, depending on the amount of functionality you want. You'd basically have a `HashMap<T, Integer>` or something like that.

Just for example:

```
class MultiSet<T> {
    Map<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    void add(T obj) {
        Integer count = map.get(obj);
        if (count == null) {
            map.put(obj, 1);
        } else {
            map.put(obj, count + 1);
        }
    }

    void remove(T obj) {
        Integer count = map.get(obj);
        if (count != null) {
            if (count > 1) {
                map.put(obj, count - 1);
            } else {
                map.remove(obj);
            }
        }
    }

    boolean contains(Object obj) {
        return map.containsKey(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Linking the `Multiset` source [[link](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.java)]

Comment: It should probably `implements Iterable<T>` or even `Collection<T>`. And now that we have Java 8, you can tidy the code significantly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What Java 8 can help with the tidiness?

Comment: @jinge a combination of `Map.computeIfAbsent` and `Map.merge` makes most of this code a on liner. Also, the `Counter` is unnecessary.

Comment: Avoids boxing by creating an extra object - no sure that really helps anything.

Comment: Plus, in modern Java boxing is not so much of an issue as the JIT can elide a large part of it. (P.S. Sorry for the double post - waited longer than 5 mins)

Comment: @jinge The `add` method in my (updated) example is a one-liner in Java 8: `map.merge(obj, 1, count -> count + 1);`. If we were fully implementing `Collection` there would be a lot more stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

One approach should be collect shuffle if you need random ordering.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
Collections.shuffle(list);

System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[B, A, C]
```